# Is there a way to calc(add,substract,divide) in function of another column in a CASE WHEN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a stored procedure in which I'd like to have a calculation done.

I'd like to know if it is possible to do a calculation in function of another column while being in a case when :

Sorry the formatting looks a bit rusty

```
USE [NG]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

PRINT 'CREATE PROCEDURE report_IQ3_2'

PRINT 'Création de la procédure report_IQ3_2'
GO

DECLARE
        @ProjectId int = 63761 ,
        @GroupID int = 20,
        @ServiceID int = -1,
        @EndDate date = '31/12/2020',
        @StartDate date = '01/07/2020',
        @StartDateN2 date = '01/01/2020'


SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    If object_id('tempdb..#TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist') is not null drop table #TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist
    If object_id('tempdb..#Iteration') is not null drop table #Iteration
    If object_id('tempdb..#TT_TAUX') is not null drop table #TT_TAUX

--Table stockant les valeurs de la première procédure.
    CREATE TABLE #TT_TAUX (
        [Tag] varchar(15),
        [LibelleTaux] varchar(255),
        [Total] numeric(15,0),
        [Keys] varchar(MAX),
        [ProjectID] int,
        Iteration int,
        StartDate date,
        EndDate date
    )
--Table finale permetatnt de stocker le calcul avec le taux et un tag.
    CREATE TABLE #TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist (
        [Tag] varchar(15),
        [LibelleTaux] varchar(255),
        [Total] numeric(15,5),
        [Keys] varchar(MAX),
        [ProjectID] int,
        Iteration int,
        StartDate date,
        Enddate date
    )

    INSERT INTO #TT_TAUX 
        EXECUTE dbo.[report_IQ3_2-05_AssistanceSupport] @ProjectId,@GroupID,@ServiceID,@StartDate,@StartDateN2,@EndDate;

        SELECT * FROM #TT_TAUX
    

-- Requête d'insertion de la ligne récupérant le code et le label du rapport, qui ensuite insert un calcul NONREP/(Demande-Abandon) *100.
    INSERT INTO #TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist 
        SELECT  
                'IQ3.2-05' AS Code,
                (SELECT Label FROM dbo.IND_IndicatorsThresholdWeighting WHERE Code = 'IQ3.2-05') AS Label,

                CASE WHEN (SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'DEMANDE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID )-(SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ABANDON' AND ProjectID = JI.ID)-(SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ATTENTE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID) =0 
                    THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 
                    ((SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'HD' AND ProjectID = JI.ID)/((SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'DEMANDE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID)-(SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ABANDON' AND ProjectID = JI.ID)-(SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ATTENTE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID))) 
                END AS Total,
                dbo.StrConcat([Keys]),
                TTA.ProjectID,
                Iteration,
                StartDate,
                EndDate

            FROM #TT_TAUX TTA
                JOIN dbo.JIRA_Projects JI ON JI.ID = TTA.ProjectID

            WHERE (@ProjectID = -1 OR JI.ID = @ProjectId)
            GROUP BY TTA.ProjectID, JI.ID, TTA.Total, TTA.Iteration, TTA.StartDate, TTA.EndDate

            SELECT * FROM #TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist


    If object_id('tempdb..#TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist') is not null drop table #TT_TotalTauxTauxAssist
    If object_id('tempdb..#TT_TAUX') is not null drop table #TT_TAUX    
END
GO

PRINT 'Fin de création de la procédure report_IQ3_2'
GO
```

I'm executing a first stored procedure which is returning me this :
[image: First Stored Procedure Result]

My calculation is basically filtering by tag

```
                CASE WHEN (
SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'DEMANDE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID )-(

SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ABANDON' AND ProjectID = JI.ID )-(

SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ATTENTE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID ) = 0
```

The problem is that it doesn't work anymore because we recently added another column called Iteration, (which is always 1 or 2)
The compiler is returning me an error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

That I do understand because he doesn't know which line he should take (i.e Tag Demande but 2 Iterations lines caused by the fact we have 2 values )

My question is, is it still possible to let him do that but for the 2 iterations values ?
ie. making the 2 calculations for each iterations ?

Comment: Are the values of Total the same in both rows?

Comment: @forpas , If you look at the screen, Total are 6 and 8. These are differents rows that have a different value in the Iteration column.

Comment: Which of the 2 totals do you want in the CASE expression? Or do you want their sum?

Comment: @forpas What I would like to do at first would be to sum the total that has a tag "demande", which is 8, minus the tag 'abandon' which is  3, and minus tag 'attente' which is 0. 

But that's only for one iteration, the second one would be like ( 6 Demande - 0 Abandon - 0 Attente ) I want my sum to be done twice for the 2 rows)

Comment: I have updated the screen with the full table so it could be clearer @forpas

Comment: Side note: I don't understand why you have the second temp table, it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to correlate the `Iteration` column also.**

> You can also simplify the `CASE` using `NULLIF`

```
(
    (
        SELECT Total
        FROM #TT_TAUX
        WHERE
            Tag = 'HD'
        AND ProjectID = JI.ID
        AND Iteration = JI.Iteration
    ) /
    NULLIF(
        (SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'DEMANDE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID AND Iteration = TTA.Iteration) -
        (SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ABANDON' AND ProjectID = JI.ID AND Iteration = TTA.Iteration) -
        (SELECT Total FROM #TT_TAUX WHERE Tag = 'ATTENTE' AND ProjectID = JI.ID AND Iteration = TTA.Iteration),
        0
    )
)
```

**However, using window functions would be even better:**

```
SELECT  
    'IQ3.2-05' AS Code,
    --
    (
        SELECT Label
        FROM dbo.IND_IndicatorsThresholdWeighting
        WHERE Code = 'IQ3.2-05'
    ) AS Label,
    --
    TotalHD /
    NULLIF(
        TotalDEMANDE - TotalABANDON - TotalATTENTE,
        0
    ) AS Total,
    --
    dbo.StrConcat([Keys]),
    TTA.ProjectID,
    Iteration,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            TotalHD      = SUM(CASE WHEN Tag = 'HD'      THEN Total END) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, Iteration),
            TotalDEMANDE = SUM(CASE WHEN Tag = 'DEMANDE' THEN Total END) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, Iteration),
            TotalABANDON = SUM(CASE WHEN Tag = 'ABANDON' THEN Total END) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, Iteration),
            TotalATTENTE = SUM(CASE WHEN Tag = 'ATTENTE' THEN Total END) OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID, Iteration)
        FROM #TT_TAUX TTA
    ) TTA
        JOIN dbo.JIRA_Projects JI
        ON JI.ID = TTA.ProjectID
WHERE
    (@ProjectID = -1 OR JI.ID = @ProjectId)
GROUP BY
    TTA.ProjectID, JI.ID, TTA.Total, TTA.Iteration, TTA.StartDate, TTA.EndDate
```

Comment: It looks like the most valid solution to me, I have yet to test it. Thank you for everything @Charlieface

Comment: Tested and validated. It works even better than what I had before, huge thanks Charlie.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was simple. I had to put TTA.Iteration = Iteration so he could relate from one Iteration value to another, I have a result and the error has gone.